# How to return a float between two numbers from a percentage

Tags: math

I am really struggling to work this one out!

If you have two numbers and a percentage, how can I return the float from the percentage point between those two numbers?

ie.

```
Min = 9
Max = 16
Percentage = 45%
```

How do I return the float thats 45% of the way between 9 and 16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Min + ((Max - Min) * Percentage)

Essentially you are finding x% of the difference between the two and progressing from the minimum.

In your case:

```
9 + ((16-9)* .45))
9 + (7*.45)
9 + (3.15)
12.15
```

Comment: thanks! i've been struggling with this for the last hour doh!